# How to setup gtag anonymize_ip? Am I doing it wrong?

Tags: google-analytics, anonymize, gtag.js

So reading by reading this [little page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/ip-anonymization), first I thought, I just have to add the following line to my gtag script and everything gonna be just fine:

```
gtag('config', '<GA_TRACKING_ID>', { 'anonymize_ip': true });
```

But today I realized that, maybe I didn't understand it right, and what I did, it's just plain stupid. :)

```
gtag('config', 'UA-2180247-1');
gtag('config', '<GA_TRACKING_ID>', { 'anonymize_ip': true });
```

So now I don't know how should the second line look:

```
gtag('config', '<UA-2180247-1>', { 'anonymize_ip': true });
```

or

```
gtag('config', 'UA-2180247-1', { 'anonymize_ip': true });
```

or there shouldn't be two lines at all, just the one which already contains the anonymize_ip...

Somehow it's not self explanatory for me, because elsewhere in documentation google has examples like this:

```
gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID');
gtag('config', '<UA-2180247-1>');
```

not like this, with these brackets ('<>'). So it's just a misspelling?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess i got my answer at the following link:
https://smarter-ecommerce.com/blog/en/analytics/implement-gdpr-compliant-ip-anonymization-google-analytics/

I've tested, and i only need one extended line like this

```
gtag('config', 'UA-2180247-1', { 'anonymize_ip': true });
```